# How to make pytest print a summary of failed tests as a list?

Tags: report, pytest

According to the docs, there are various ways to print the pytest summary:

https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html

However, I can't see there an example how to make the summary to have a list of failed test, similar to coverage report.

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Isn't the `-r` flag what you are looking for? `pytest -rf` will print an extra section named `short test summary info` listing only failed tests.

Comment: in this call I get though only the summary and the rest gets captured:
``python3  -m pytest  -rfs tests/``

Comment: I don't understand; what is the desired output you are trying to achieve?

Comment: all the normal output as with -s and then a summary of failed tests.